# Как подключится к https серверу?

Tags: c++, сокет

Пытаюсь подключится к серверу таким образом:

```
    int sock = 0;
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        cout << "socket() error: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";

    sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("149.154.167.99");

    sin.sin_port = htons(443);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if(connect(sock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sin), sizeof (sin)) == -1)
        cout << "connect error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
```

Входит в тело условия connect(), с 80 портом и другим хостом работает. Пытаюсь таким образом изучить принцип работы https. Подскажите пожалуйста разобраться, почему не подключается к серверу

Comment: Ну если к другим серверам подключается, а к этому нет, то попробуйте через командную строку  пропинговать этот сервер, может быть он не доступен

Comment: @helldrg ко всем http (80 порт) подключается. я не могу подключится по 443 порту ни к какому сайту

Comment: еще есть вариант, что сервер по адресу 149.154.167.99 не прослушивает данный порт. А сервер запущен у вас на компьютере?

Comment: @helldrg это ip адрес хоста для запросов telegram API, мне только клиент нужно запускать

Comment: @sddxvd а с 80 портом получается подключиться? У меня не получится подключиться не с каким портом, потому что провайдер блокирует этот сервер

Comment: @helldrg не получается

Comment: у вас скорее всего тоже провайдер блокирует этот адрес. Попробуйте найти зеркало этого сервера и к нему подключайтесь. Что бы проверить блокирует зеркало или нет, через консоль пингуйте адрес

Comment: @helldrg спасибо большое. понять не могу, в чем дело, а я с браузера сижу с прокси. этот адрес действительно заблокирован, теперь не пойму что делать

Comment: ну как вариант, я сам не делал такое, установить себе что то наподобие Advanced Onion Router, только что бы работало с вашей программой